# How to run Windows command prompt utilities options in Git Bash (how to specify /slash options)?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

An example that doesn't work in Git Bash but only in Windows prompt:

```
// Git Bash
$ ipconfig /all
Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.

// Windows
User> ipconfig /all
C:\Users\sergey>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : HOST-12345
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : NodeType
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   ... so on
```

How to provide slash option in Git Bash `/all`, `/renew`, etc

Comment: i'm curious, do you find git bash has any advantage over just adding git to the path?

Comment: @barlop, It has many UNIX utilities enabled, like `ls`, `ll`, `touch`, `cat`, `curl`, `ssh`, so on. Copy on select. Place command line cursor by click. It has colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the slash to a dash. At least it did work for me on 1.9.4 on Windows 7.

```
$ ipconfig -all
```

Alternatively escape the `/` by using `\/`.

```
$ ipconfig \/all
```

Comment: Escape didn't work for me, but a dash did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It should be `ipconfig //all` (two forward slashes).
It also works in git bash; this is what is called POSIX path conversion and is [documented here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

Comment: it help. but if the code is in a bat file. it won't work.